# Upload file(not new) to google drive using php

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api

I'm learning how to use API of google drive via PHP, and with the following code I have added a new file to my google drive. If I want to add an exisisting file that is already on my desktop for example, what should I change in this script?

```
<?php

// inclusione delle librerie del client
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

// istanza dell'oggetto di classe relativo al client
$drive = new Google_Client();

// credenziali per l'autenticazione
$drive->setClientId('id');
$drive->setClientSecret('secret');
$drive->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$drive->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

// istanza dell'oggetto di classe relativo al servizio
$gdrive = new Google_DriveService($drive);

// salvataggio del token in una variabile
$_GET['code']= 'code';

// memorizzazione del token in un file
file_put_contents('token.json', $drive->authenticate());

// lettura delle informazioni contenute nel file
$drive->setAccessToken(file_get_contents('token.json'));

// istanza dell'oggetto di classe relativo al file per i test
$doc = new Google_DriveFile();

// intestazioni per il file di test
$doc->setTitle('Test Progetto Drive');
$doc->setDescription('Documento di prova');
$doc->setMimeType('text/plain');

// lettura del contenuto del file e restituzione sotto forma di stringa
$content = file_get_contents('progettodrive.txt');

// generazione del file per il test
$output = $gdrive->files->insert($doc, array(
'data' => $content,
'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
));

// stampa del risultato
print_r($output);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $files= array();
$dir = dir('files');
while ($file = $dir->read()) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}
$dir->close();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
    foreach ($files as $file_name) {
        $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
        $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
        $file->setTitle($file_name);
        $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
        $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
        $service->files->insert(
            $file,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                'mimeType' => $mime_type
            )
        );
    }
    finfo_close($finfo);
    header('location:'.$url);exit;
}
include 'index.phtml';
```

Comment: which are the parameters that I have to change?